# Display user's total comment count outside The Loop

Tags: php, comments, users, count

How do I display a user's total comment count outside The Loop?

I use this code to display comment count **inside the loop**:

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $post->post_author;
    $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;
    $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total
    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
    {$where}
");
    echo 'Comments: <strong>' . $comment_count . '</strong>';
    ?>
```

That works perfectly inside the loop. In an attempt to make that code work outside the loop, I changed `$user_id = $post->post_author;` to `$user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );` but it did not work.

The closest that I have been is with this code:

```
                            <?php
                            global $wpdb;
                            $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
                            $comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
                                SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
                                FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                                {$where}
                                GROUP BY user_id
                                ", object);
                            foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
                                $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
                                echo 'Comments: ' . $count->total . '
                                ';
                            }
                            ?>
```

However, this echos comment count for all users, like this: "Comments: 28 Comments: 11 Comments: 55" etc

What code can I use to **show the user's comment count outside the loop**?

Answer (score 4):

You are more or less there already with the code, you just need to change the code slightly.

You do not mention *how* you get the user id, but if you have the user ID you want to check, it is quite easy to do outside the loop.

Here is a simple example:

```
$userid=1;
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = %s", $userid ) );
echo "Number of comments for user $userid is $comment_count";
```

Note: the part of the query that says "comment_approved = 1" counts only the approved comments, if you want to include the non-approved comments leave out that part.